# How can I mitigate the keylogging issue of Xorg?

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, wayland, firejail, xephyr

My plan is to:

- Turn off listening to all sockets, and initiate X through a command
  such as: `Xorg -nolisten tcp -nolisten inet -nolisten inet6 -nolisten unix -nolisten local :0 -seat seat0 vt7 -novtswitch` (although I don't know how to prevent X running entirely without this configuration)
- Run Xorg rootless - which is far more difficult than it seems
  considering I don't want to use GNOME or GDM. At the moment I'm using
  LightDM and XFCE. I did manage to get rootless Xorg working on SDDM,
  but it's quite buggy. Again the insanity of this baffles me.
- FireJail the main X server and only allow communication through for
  specific inputs (keyboard, mouse, screen, Xephyr). So for this I'd
  prevent anything speaking to the X server directly other than these
  applications/devices, thereby forcing GUI applications to use the
  proxy of Xephyr. It should also keep everything sandboxed to
  hopefully prevent possible zero-day attacks.
- Use seccomp namespacing through FireJail on both applications and the X server to try and further isolate everything

However the reality of implementing these measures is much more difficult than I realised, as I've seen with FireJail and Xephyr not preventing keylogging still. Is there anything I should add to this above list? It would be good if we could compile a list in this thread of all the possible fixes to help other people out who are also probably struggling in the same way.

What kind of protections do you guys have in place to prevent keylogging (and other issues) on X11 and Xorg? This is a huge issue which affects just about every GUI computer which runs Linux so I absolutely can't and don't believe there's nothing which can be done to prevent this as it's such a notorious issue.

Really interested to hear what you all think.

Comment: This is not a forum, and not a place for discussion or sharing opinion. Please keep questions short and focused on the technical issue. Those of you who want to answer can post an answer, but don't start long discussion in the comments. That's what chat, where the previous comments [have been moved](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142259/discussion-on-question-by-chris98-how-can-i-mitigate-the-keylogging-issue-of-xor), is for.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, not running "malware" is what protects you from such issues. If you must run Xorg and are very concerned about that specific issue, you might want to consider simply running multiple servers on different `TTY`s (will not work with logind).

I haven't tried this, but it should be possible to run e.g. `startxfce4` on multiple `TTY`s. [Systemd does not currently support multiple sessions per user.](https://systemd.io/DESKTOP_ENVIRONMENTS/)

So you could spawn these sessions without systemd. In addition, you will need separate files such as `.Xauthority`.
This is the only untested solution I can come up with.
With this, you **should** get multiple desktop sessions that **shouldn't** be able to communicate with each other.

But, with multiple users - 1 per session, you can still use systemd with minimal changes. It's not optimal either, but should work too.

Keep in mind that making your DE not use systemd and the general configuration might be some work and a non-systemd system may be required.

But when you want to run "malware", that won't be the only/least concern and you might want to isolate the system on the hardware front.

Comment: Thanks for this I appreciate it. I'll look into it and let you know how I get on with it.

Comment: Sure, I think you question is valid - though perceived as a rant by some. I've updated my answer, multiple users might save you some work. I know it's not on optimal solution, but considering the lack of other software and the inherent problem, such workarounds seem like the only viable solution.